# Calling GET /api/users/{login} with email

Tags: rest, jhipster

I have problem customizing JHipster built-int service:  /api/users/{login}, as I want my logins to be emails.
I'm testing requests with JHipster builtin Swagger:

"helloworld@gmailcom" - REST call return 406 - HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException
"helloworld@gmail.com" - REST call passes error, returns 404

found this topic, that problems are caused by "." :

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3338

what would be solution, if I want to make REST service with email parameter?

Comment: Your question lacks detals. How do you make your request, do you set accept header to specify json format? Have you tried to URI encode your email like /api/users/helloworld%40gmail%2Ecom ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, my problem was caused by Spring ContentNegotiationConfigurer feature.
After adding this to configuration requests worked:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
}
```